# this regarding an issue I have regarding Jquery's accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm experimenting with jquery user interface and trying to make an accordion menu. I'm unable to get the menu to function as demonstrated in the example: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ 
I do not have a specific question regarding this since I don't know where my error is. I'll appreciate it if you inspect my code and mark my error. thanks

here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.css" />
        <style type="text/css" title="text/css">
            body {
                width:60%;
            }
            h1.ui-accordion-header {
                font-size : 10px;
            }
            div.ui-accordion-content {
                font-size : 15px;
                font-family : georgia;
            }
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
             $(document).ready(function() { 
              $( "#ui-accordion-header" ).accordion();
             });

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="ui-accordion-header"  style="height:250px;margin-bottom:1em;">
                <ul>  
                    <li>
                        <a>   Guitar</a>
                        <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>  Electric</a></li>
                            <li><a>  Acoustic</a></li>
                            <li><a>  Amps</a></li>
                            <li><a>  Effects A</a></li>
                            <li><a>  Effects B</a></li>
                            <li><a>  Effects C</a></li>
                            <li><a>  Effects D</a></li>
                            <li><a>  Accessories</a></li>
                        </ul> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    </div>
                        <a>  Bass</a>
                        <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>  Electric</a></li>
                            <li><a>  Acoustic</a></li>
                            <li><a>  Amps</a></li>
                            <li><a>  Effects</a></li>
                            <li><a>  Accessories</a></li>
                        </ul> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    </div>
                        <a>  Drums</a>
                        <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>  Acoustic Drums</a></li>
                            <li><a>  Electronic Drums</a></li>
                            <li><a>  Cymbals</a></li>
                            <li><a>  Hardware</a></li>
                            <li><a>  Accessories</a></li>
                        </ul> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors, or done any basic debugging yourself?

Comment: i did the inspection. I only get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: You have extra }); in your script. And your html doesn't follow the structure which is required for accordion.

Comment: I made the adjustments but still can't get the accordion effect

Comment: Refer this example :http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#entry-examples for html structure.

Comment: I think I have copied the example but still cannot get it to work

Comment: I edited the previous code to the new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `accordian` you have to follow basic html structure like below

```
<div id="accordian">
 <h3>title1</h3>
 <div>content1</div>
 <h3>title2</h3>
 <div>content2</div>
</div>
```

and include jquery-UI library which is not available with version 1.11.1, so add it externally.

Use below HTML code -

```
  <div id="ui-accordion-header"  style="height:250px;margin-bottom:1em;">

                            <h3>  Guitar</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a>  Electric</a></li>
                                <li><a>  Acoustic</a></li>
                                <li><a>  Amps</a></li>
                                <li><a>  Effects A</a></li>
                                <li><a>  Effects B</a></li>
                                <li><a>  Effects C</a></li>
                                <li><a>  Effects D</a></li>
                                <li><a>  Accessories</a></li>
                            </ul> 
                            <h3>  Bass</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a>  Electric</a></li>
                                <li><a>  Acoustic</a></li>
                                <li><a>  Amps</a></li>
                                <li><a>  Effects</a></li>
                                <li><a>  Accessories</a></li>
                            </ul> 
                            <h3>  Drums</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a>  Acoustic Drums</a></li>
                                <li><a>  Electronic Drums</a></li>
                                <li><a>  Cymbals</a></li>
                                <li><a>  Hardware</a></li>
                                <li><a>  Accessories</a></li>
                            </ul> 
                </div>
```

And remove extra `});` from `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $( "#ui-accordion-header" ).accordion();
 });
```

[**Accordian Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0wayd94s/6/)